# Flutter: Is there a way to know when a listview builder is loaded?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im new in flutter and im not completly sure about the listview builder behaviour, im doing a screen which has a listview builder with multiple cards, each one with different info and background image. My problem is when the app is launched for the 1st time, it takes maybe 0.5sec to load and build the cards with their assets and the user sees the cards with white background in the meantime(its short but still kinda ugly). I tried to use a boolean in true at the start,show a container with circular progress indicator, after a 0.5 delay set the boolean to false and then change for the the listview. It didnt work since the listview is loaded when its called so i dont know what can i do to solve this.

This is what i tried

```
void initState(){
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    });
  }


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return loading ? circleLoading() : Scaffold(
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 FutureBuilder(
              future: //API CALL,
              initialData: [],
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.isEmpty) 
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());  //CIRCULAR INDICATOR
                else
                    return createTasksListView(context, snapshot);
              }),
        ),
```

Comment: what should i put in future? sorry im new in this

Comment: just put your future method or api calling method